# Open CV 3.0.0 video not processing windows winpython 2.7.9

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I wrote the following code to open a video file and the file is in the same directory as the script, moreover the code to write a video feed from the camera to the file is not working!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('F:/vtest.avi')
print cap.isOpened()
if(cap.isOpened()== False):
    cap.open('F://vtest.avi')
    print cap.isOpened()
while(cap.read()):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But the code threw the following errors. I tried moving the ffmpeg.dll file in Python directory but to no avail.

```
False
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\2.py", line 11, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3480: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one convert a grayscale image to RGB in OpenCV (Python) for visualizing contours after processing an image in binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21596281/how-does-one-convert-a-grayscale-image-to-rgb-in-opencv-python-for-visualizing)

Comment: @samer its no duplicate... these two are entirely different problems!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('F:/vtest.avi')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Also, place the video in the same directory as this script and check if it works.

Comment: Have you tried the code while keeping the video file in the same directory?

Comment: yes its in the same directory n i just gave the filename... not after that even

Comment: Well, then I guess that its a problem with your ffmpeg. Try reinstalling it?